# How to show data from a BLE device in multiple Textviews?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I have a humidity sensor that broadcasts the last ten values as a single array after a fixed time interval. I want to display these values in ten `Textview`'s.

My current code displays all the values in a single `TextView`, how can I modify this?
How could it possible?

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                 BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        if (BleUuid.READ_SENSOR
                .equalsIgnoreCase(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
            final String values = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
            byte[] bytes =values.getBytes();
            final String value = new String(bytes);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    statuslv.setText(value);
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: please add the format of the current String.

Comment: ble sends sensor reading values to the app..

Comment: like int values, 30,40,50,60...

Comment: Then the answer I supplied should be able to split that String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the String you receive.

Depending on the format, you should be able to use something like this

```
String[] parts = string.split(","); //this should use the character(s) which separate your results
```

If you really want to show the results in 10 different TextViews, then you can do

```
textView1.setText(parts[0]);
textView2.setText(parts[1]);
//...
```

You could also put the results in a ListView.

Comment: My received String is final String value = new String(bytes); But how will i split the String value that contains my data for checking with if else

Comment: If this is a new question, please open a new question or edit your existing one.

Comment: yes. i done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470865/how-will-i-split-a-string-that-received-from-a-ble-device-for-if-else-checking-a?noredirect=1#comment50907405_31470865