# How will i Split a String that received from a ble device for if else checking and display a value on Textview

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble

In my Android app I receive data from my ble device as something like 10100201201511 ( it includes date,time and other attributes).

I hope I received it as a string, I want to check that value and display it on textview.

My Requirement is

```
If (position1=0){
  //display yes in Text view
}else
{ // display No in Textview 
}
```

But I always get errors like `Array type expected; found 'Java.lang.String'`

My current code is:

```
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                if (BleUuid.READ_TIME
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                    final String names = characteristic.getStringValue(0);


                    if (names[0]=0){
                        line1.setText("got it");
                    }
                    else{
                        line1.setText("Nil");
                    }
```

Plz help me to resolve this..

Comment: Why do you try to convert you string to a byte array and again to a string ? Can't you just use `names` ? It's already a String, isn't it ?

Comment: yes . i removed that and try to run like u said. but the error shows .array required,But String found.

Comment: I've never worked with bluetooth myself, but an obvious mistake is that you're trying to use `names` as an `Array`. That is not possible. Aside from that, if you want to compare 2 Strings, you should do it like `"0".equals(someString)`

Comment: Okay Leave about Bluetooth.. Can we convert this  "names"  to array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error occurs at `names[0]=0` because `names` is a string.

If you want to read the first letter of the string use

```
   if ( !names.isEmpty() && names.substring(0,1).equals("0"))
         line1.setText("got it");
   else
         line1.setText("Nil");
```

Comment: This code is partially working for me now. but it always shows the else part.

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu Then that's because your string does not contains "0" as the first character. Add a print statement for debugging to see what is your string.

Comment: It Worked for me now..    Brother . I had  one more doubt. how will i set a substring value to a textview. like  line1.setText(???).                                                                               For Example ,I am receiving date and time in that string. i need to show date and time separately in different textviews

Comment: calling the substring method on a string return a new string of the size chosen in the parameters. If you need to have two substrings, use `String a = names.substring(x,y);` and `String b = names.substring(x', y');` then pass your string to your TextView objects (replacing x, y, x' and y' by the values you need, check the javadoc of substring http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))